# GROUP BY with OVER

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these 2 tables:

transactions table

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 2  |
+----+
| 3  |
+----+
```

entries table

```
+----+----------------+--------+---------+
| id | transaction_id | income | expense |
+----+----------------+--------+---------+
| A  | 1              |        | 500     |
+----+----------------+--------+---------+
| B  | 2              | 250    |         |
+----+----------------+--------+---------+
| C  | 2              | 250    |         |
+----+----------------+--------+---------+
```

This query works just fine:

```
SELECT e.income, e.expense, sum(e.income - e.expense) OVER (ORDER BY e.id) AS cumulative_sum
FROM entries e
JOIN transactions t on t.id = e.transaction_id;
```

But I need a query that looks like this (it doesn't work):

```
SELECT sum(e.income), sum(e.expense), sum(e.income-e.expense) OVER (ORDER BY e.id) AS cumulative_sum
FROM entries e
JOIN transactions t on t.id = e.transaction_id
GROUP by t.id;
```

So I can get the following result:

```
+----------------+--------+---------+---------+
| transaction_id | income | expense | balance |
+----------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 1              |        | 500     | 500     |
+----------------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2              | 500    |         | 0       |
+----------------+--------+---------+---------+
```

The error I get from previous query:

```
Error : Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'e.income' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

The error is referencing to column specified here "sum(e.income - e.expense) OVER..."

So how can I actually use OVER and GROUP BY for this scenario? Or is there any other solution using a derived table with cross joins? Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to order by `entries.id` after you have grouped rows by transaction's id? `entries.id` is not present in that context and it is not clear how to group by records when you have calculated running total.

Comment: On a side note: the join to `transactions` is superfluous in your query. You only use its ID, which you already have in the `entries` table.

Comment: The error you are seeing is that `sum(e.income-e.expense)` is part of the original aggregation. You cannot just add an `OVER` clause to it. You would have to use a function, e.g. `SUM(sum(e.income-e.expense)) OVER ...`.

Comment: I think the balance in the sample result should be -500 instead of 500 by the way.

Comment: Do you actually want to compress transaction_id #2 into one row or is that a mistake?

Comment: What is the primary key in the `entries` table?  You've made some changes which might be a problem.  You no longer have an entry for the 3rd transaction.

Comment: @Salman: It seems this is what this request is all about. OP understands how to get a running total when showing all entries, but they want to show the transactions with a running total instead.

Comment: `e.id` is not available after group by and cannot be used inside window functions. Why exactly do you want to order by `e.id` and not `t.id` or something functionally dependent on transaction e.g. transaction.date (if such a column exist)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised `sum(e.income - e.expense)` works for you. With either income or expense being NULL in your rows, all calculated differences should result in null and hence their sum, too.

You should have `sum(e.income) - sum(e.expense)` instead and even use `COALESCE` for the case there is no income or no expense at all.

Anyway, you want to get from this plain aggregation per transaction:

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  SUM(e.income) AS total_income,
  SUM(e.expense) AS total_expense,
  COALESCE(SUM(e.income), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(e.expense), 0) AS balance
FROM entries e
JOIN transactions t on t.id = e.transaction_id
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.id;
```

to a running balance total. For this just add

```
SUM(COALESCE(SUM(e.income), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(e.expense), 0))
  OVER (ORDER BY t.id) AS cumulated_balance
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT sum(e.income)  OVER (ORDER BY e.id) AS cum_income
     , sum(e.expense) OVER (ORDER BY e.id) AS cum_expense
     , COALESCE(sum(e.income)  OVER (ORDER BY e.id), 0)
     - COALESCE(sum(e.expense) OVER (ORDER BY e.id), 0) AS cumulative_sum
  FROM entries e
  JOIN transactions t on t.id = e.transaction_id
 ORDER BY e.transaction_id, e.id
;
```

Not sure which ordering you want.

Comment: `coalesce(sum(...), 0) over(...) - coalesce(sum(...), 0) over(...)` to handle nulls

Answer (score 1):

Every `sum()` needs its own `OVER` clause and you don't want a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT e.transaction_id,
       sum(e.income) OVER (ORDER BY e.id) AS cumulative_income,
       sum(e.expense) OVER (ORDER BY e.id) AS cumulative_expense,
       sum(e.income) OVER (ORDER BY e.id)
       - sum(e.expense) OVER (ORDER BY e.id) AS cumulative_sum
       FROM entries e
            INNER JOIN transactions t
                       ON t.id = e.transaction_id;
```

Or you can use named windows, if you don't want to repeat the `OVER` clause (but still it needs to be assigned to each `sum()` individually).

```
SELECT e.transaction_id,
       sum(e.income) OVER w AS cumulative_income,
       sum(e.expense) OVER w AS cumulative_expense,
       sum(e.income) OVER w
       - sum(e.expense) OVER w AS cumulative_sum
       FROM entries e
            INNER JOIN transactions t
                       ON t.id = e.transaction_id
       WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY e.id);
```